# What is a word/noun to describe someone who authors a project but doesn't produce it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a one-word noun to describe someone who posts a project idea for a freelancer to pick up. They describe the project and project need, but they are not the producer. For example, "I'm in need of a logo for my business. I'm the "?", and the person who will design the logo is the producer."

Comment: Wouldn't that be the client?

Comment: Sponsor or benefactor?

Comment: project initiator

Answer (score 1):

I believe sponsor is the word used, in the corporate world at least

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_sponsorship

Answer (score 1):

In my experience as a designer, that person is in the vast majority of cases referred to as the 'client'. In some in-house scenarios I have seen them called the 'originator' of the project.

Answer (score 0):

In television parlance, you are the *creator* of the show, and may carry over to projects in general.

Comment: Can you cite a reference for this answer, Cord?

Comment: Only the roughly ten thousand shows I've seen with the attribution "created by..."  Wikipedia discusses some of the complications of the title Creator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_program_creators